# Separate Mesh for each Letter

Tags: text-object

I need to convert each letter of a text object into an individual mesh. I have tried to convert the text into a mesh and then separate by loose parts, however, that has the unintended side-effect that all i-dots, colons, etc. get separated from their main parts. I could merge these manually, but that would be rather cumbersome. Is there a way to create exactly one mesh per letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install animation nodes addon, there's a text > object separate node that works as an operator...

more info:

you just need one node, that acts as an operator, press separate or update...
the algorithm counts the number of splines on each glyph to do it correctly; 
node also allows you to have text / curve or mesh output

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots or elaborate more on this topic?

Comment: This works perfectly. For the lazy, download [animation nodes here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?350296-Addon-Animation-Nodes)

Answer (score 2):

You could go into edit mode turn on the option to able to see through objects in edit mode(this allows you to select vertex on the other side of an object)(if you don't know where it is, it is in-between proportional editing and the boxes for single, edge, or face select) all you would have to do then is press "B" and drag select the letters, commas, dots, you wish and press "CTRL"+"V" or "P" and click "Separate" - then - "by Selection" this will make the selected a separate mesh.

Comment: This to me seems almost as cumbersome as separating by loose parts, then joining the ones that belong together. With just a few words, it'd be perfectly doable, but try doing it with a Star Wars crawler. Then imagine doing that Star Wars crawler in a language that uses lots of diacritics, e.g. German, French, or the Scandinavian or Slavic languages.

Comment: Yeah, in that case it would probably be faster to do the separation by lose parts and the selecting dots and dashes and such and joining them with CTRL + J