# How to make each letter a single object?

Tags: animation, mesh, text-object

I <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and added a Text, then I <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to convert it into a mesh.

Even though the object is not interconnected, it is considered as a single object.

My goal is to make each letter a single object so I can perform a rotation animation on each one letter separately.

How do I separate them?

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67294/separate-mesh-for-each-letter

Answer (score 5):

[image: Finnal]

With converted **Text** to **Mesh** go to **Edit Mode**, **Select All** (<kbd>A</kbd>) then hit <kbd>P</kbd> and choose '**By loose parts**'.

Comment: If the text has any extrusion, between select all and separate by loose parts, you would also want to remove doubles to get the front, back and side pieces joined together.

Comment: Does this work with disconnected letters like _i_?